# Markers not showing on Google Map in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-maps, cron, google-maps-markers

I have created a Google App Engine project in Python it runs on my localhost but when I upload it onto geo-event-maps.appspot.com the markers are not displaying.
I have a cron which runs to call on /place.
I have no log errors
My datastore is empty!
The txt files are being uploaded with:

```
    file_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    path = os.path.join(file_path, 'storing', 'txtFiles')
```

Is there a way of checking the files have been uploaded?!

I am at an absolute loss.  Has anyone had these problems before?

Below is my main.py:

```
    '''
Created on Mar 30, 2011

@author: kimmasterson
'''
#!/usr/bin/env python

from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext import db
from placemaker import placemaker
import logging
import  wsgiref.handlers
import os, glob
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template


class Story(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty()
    loc_name = db.StringProperty()
    title = db.StringProperty()
    long = db.FloatProperty()
    lat = db.FloatProperty()
    link = db.StringProperty()
    date = db.StringProperty()
class MyStories(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        temp = db.Query(Story)
        temp = temp.count()


        story_set = Story.all()

        template_values = {
            'storyTemp': story_set
        }

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
class place(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        #path = '/storing/txtFiles'
        file_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        path = os.path.join(file_path, 'storing', 'txtFiles')

        try:
            for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
                    #print infile
                    f = open(infile, 'r')
                    data = f.read()
                    newfile = infile.replace('.txt', '')
                    newfile = newfile.replace('/storing/txtFiles/', '')
                    #print newfile
                    storyname = 'http://www.independent.ie/national-news/' + newfile
                    #print storyname
                    #print newfile
                    #logging.info(data)
                    p = placemaker('HSnG9pPV34EUBcexz.tDYuSrZ8Hnp.LowswI7TxreF8sXrdpVyVIKB4uPGXBYOA9VjjF1Ca42ipd_KhdJsKYjI5cXRo0eJM-')
                    print p.find_places(data)
                    for place in p.places:
                        splitted = place.name.split()
                        for word in splitted:
                            temp = db.Query(Story)
                            temp = temp.filter("link = ", storyname)
                            results = temp.fetch(limit=1)
                            if len(results) > 0:
                                break
                            elif 'IE' in word:
                                print temp
                                print 'success'
                                print 'name of the file is:' + newfile
                                story = Story(name=newfile, long=place.centroid.longitude, lat=place.centroid.latitude, link=storyname, loc_name=place.name, title=newfile).put()
                                #logging.info(type(place.centroid.latitude))    
        except:
            print 'error'

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MyStories), ('/place', place)],
                                         debug=True)

    wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is my cron.yaml

```
    cron:
- description: running place
  url: /place
  schedule: every day 11:05
```

App.yaml is as follows:

```
application: geo-event-maps
version: 2
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.py
builtins:
- datastore_admin: on
```

Comment: Does this work locally using dev_appserver at all? are you sure your `infile in glob.glob(...` block is running? Maybe your files are not where you expect them to be in production. I think you should narrow down the problem a little and update your post.

Comment: Thats what I was wondering how I find out if my files are being added onto the server. It works on local host and the map shoes up on my appspot but just no markers because the datastore is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be sure your files are being uploaded with your application code, they can not be marked as static files or they won't be accessible to your code.  Run appcfg.py with the `--verbose` flag and make sure they get uploaded.

Second issue, in your `place` class you define path as `path = '/storing/txtFiles'`.  That is wrong.  Your path will probably be something more like:

```
file_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
path = os.path.join(file_path, 'storing', 'txtFiles')
```

Also, I suggest you don't use `print`, instead use `self.response.out.write(stuff_to_write)`.

You might also want to see about using key_names.  You'll be able to make your code quite a bit more efficient then by running a batch db.get instead of a db.Query inside a nested for-loop.  Use [Appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html) and try to minimize the number of RPCs.

Comment: You should probably use `logging.debug(stuff_to_write)` rather than returning things in the response which will not be visible when called via cron/taskqueue.

Comment: @Chris Yup, using logging.debug() would probably be better.  All those print calls kind of looked like temporary debugging aids for use when directly calling the url for testing purposes.

Comment: I changed my main.py to read in each HTML file and add the bits I need to the datastore and just queried the datastore rather than trying to load files.
Thanks for your help much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you are accessing your files using a *relative* path.

Next ensure you have not marked the files as static within your `app.yaml` as static files are not uploaded to the same place as your application (they are sent somewhere that the Google Frontend servers can serve them more directly).

Comment: When I deploy the application It is displaying "Cloning 919 application files.
Cloned 100 files.
Cloned 200 files.
Cloned 300 files.
Cloned 400 files.
Cloned 500 files.
Cloned 600 files.
Cloned 700 files.
Cloned 800 files.
Cloned 900 files.
"

Does this mean the files are definitely getting uploaded to the server?

Comment: The point is not wether they are being uploaded (which they *will* be) the point is wether they are being uploaded to the GAE static fileserver or to the GAE application server. You python code can only access things being sent to your application server, so if your `txt` file is in a directory marked as static in `app.yaml` you will not be able to `open()` it.